# typescript+THREE: Class 'Vertex' incorrectly extends base class 'Vector3'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

using THREE librarye with @types/three definition

trying to make own class extends THREE.Vector3

```
export class Vertex extends THREE.Vector3  {

constructor(
    x:number,
    y:number,
    z:number,
    public normal:THREE.Vector3 = new THREE.Vector3(),
    public uv:THREE.Vector2 = new THREE.Vector2())
{
  super(x,y,z);
}

clone():Vertex
{
  return new Vertex(this.x, this.y, this.z, this.normal.clone(), this.uv.clone());
}
```

but getting  error:

> ```
> TS2415: Class 'Vertex' incorrectly extends base class 'Vector3'.
> ```
>
> Types of property 'clone' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => Vertex' is not assignable to type '() => this'.
>         Type 'Vertex' is not assignable to type 'this'.

in THREE definition vector3 defined as:

```
export class Vector3 implements Vector {
constructor(x?: number, y?: number, z?: number);

x: number;
y: number;
z: number;
clone(): this;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `clone()` method of `Vector3` is using [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) as its return type.  What that means is that every subclass/implementation of `Vector3` needs its `clone()` method to return an instance of *that very subclass*.  On first glance, it looks like you're doing that with `Vertex`, since you are returning a `Vertex`.  But what if I did this:

```
export class SillyVertex extends Vertex {
  sillinessFactor: boolean = true;
  constructor()    
    super(0, 0, 0, new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector2());
  }
}
```

Notice that `SillyVertex` is a subclass of `Vertex`, yet it inherits its `clone()` method from `Vertex`.  So although `(new SillyVertex()).clone()` should return a `SillyVertex` according to the definition of `Vector3`, it will be a `Vertex`.  That's not correct.

---

If you know for a fact nobody's going to subclass `Vertex`, you could always leave the `this` return type and do a type assertion in the body:

```
clone(): this {
  return new Vertex(this.x, this.y, this.z, this.normal.clone(), this.uv.clone()) as this;
}
```

There's [no `final` keyword](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8306) to mark a class as non-extendable, but adding a private constructor or property will have the same effect.

---

If you *do* want to subclass `Vertex`, then you will either need a more general `clone()` method that takes care of all possible subclasses (hard to do in general, but maybe something like [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) can help you) or be careful to implement `clone()` properly in each subclass.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!